# Embed.ly API: player.js not working with youku.com

Tags: javascript, api, embedly, youku

I have a problem with embedded video. I use "Embed.ly API" and "player.js":
https://docs.embed.ly/docs/oembed

https://docs.embed.ly/docs/playerjs

I'm trying to embed a video from "youku.com" on my site. The "youku.com" is a content provider, as stated here: https://embed.ly/providers
Video is added but player's methods (play, pause and others) does not work for video. But if I changing video service from "youku.com" to "youtube.com" and use video from "youtube.com", then methods works well.

I also tried to connect the "platform.js" instead of the player. The result is the same. 
Maybe the "player.js" worked before, I guess that the "youku.com" has changed its API, but the "player.js" did not track changes.

**Does the player.js really work with "youku.com" now? Perhaps something should be added to my code for solve the problem? I am not in China, can it have any effect due to the fact that "youku.com" is a Chinese service?**

Thanks.

My code js:   (And another question: **are there any errors in the code?**)

```
      var obj_json = $.getJSON('https://api.embedly.com/1/oembed?' + $.param({
    url: :url,  // for example:  https://v.youku.com/v_show/id_XMzg2MjgwNzA0OA==.html 
    key: :key  // my_API_key
  })).done(function () {
    $('.embeded').html(obj_json.responseJSON.html).find('iframe.embedly-embed').each(function () {

      // initialize the player.
      var player = new playerjs.Player(this);

      player.on('ready', function () {
        player.setLoop(true); // it is not work 
        player.play(); // it is not work 
        //..................................
        //  There are also special buttons on the page, clicking on which the video should start or stop:
       $('.button_play').click(function () { 
            player.play();  // pressing occurs, but player it is not work 
        });
        $('.button_pause').click(function () { 
            player.pause();  // pressing occurs, but player it is not work 
        });
        //.........................................
      });
     });
    });
```

Comment: Any errors if you use the F12 tools in the browser?

Comment: No errors. Only warnings.

Comment: Warnings:
1) [Deprecation] Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.
2) Midi access has been blocked because of a Feature Policy applied to the current document.
3) [Deprecation] The deviceorientation event is deprecated on insecure origins, and support will be removed in the future. You should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS.
4) The deviceorientation events are blocked by feature policy.

Comment: Warnings next:
5) Mixed Content: The page at  https:// player.youku.com/embed/.....   was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image http:// r4.ykimg.com/051000005B7F6CD5AD8F6D0D8106694B This content should also be served over HTTPS.
6) Mixed Content: The page at  https:// player.youku.com/embed/.......  was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure video http:// vali.cp31.ott.cibntv.net/......... This content should also be served over HTTPS.